# React-Redux Application: 'props' is not defined'

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, react-props

I am creating a React-Redux application. Before adding the content above `render()`, `props` was defined. However, after I started adding said content, the app began having problems reading the variable. I don't know what happened.

Could somebody please help me understand why `props` isn't being recognized anymore? I'd really appreciate it.

**Login.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import './login.css';

class LoginForm extends React.Component { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: ''
    }

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
  }

render() {
    return (
        <>
          <Modal show={props.modalOpen} onHide={props.handleModalOpen}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
              <Modal.Title>Login</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
              <Form>
                <Form.Group>
                  <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control 
                    type="text"
                    name="username"
                    className="form-control"
                  />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group>
                  <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control 
                    type="text"
                    name="password"
                    className="form-control"
                  />
                </Form.Group>
              </Form>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
              <Button variant="danger" type="submit" onClick={props.handleModalOpen}>
                Submit
              </Button>
              <Button variant="primary" onClick={props.handleClose}>
                Cancel
              </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>  
          </Modal>
        </>
     );
  }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

**Navbar.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './navbar.css';
import LoginForm from '../LoginForm/login.js';
// import SignUpModal from '../SignUpModal/signup.js';


class Navbar extends React.Component {
  state = {
     modalOpen: false
  }

  handleModalOpen = () => {
     this.setState((prevState) => {
        return {
           modalOpen: !prevState.modalOpen
        }
     })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark px-sm-5">
            <div className="container">
                <Link to='/'>
                    <div className="navbar-brand">
                        <i class="fas fa-globe fa-2x"></i>
                    </div>
                </Link>

                <ul className="navbar-nav align-items-right">
                    <li className="nav-item ml-5">
                        <a onClick={this.handleModalOpen} className="nav-link">
                            Login
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item ml-5">
                        <a onClick={this.handleModalOpen} className="nav-link">
                            Sign Up
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <LoginForm
           modalOpen={this.state.modalOpen}
           handleModalOpen={this.handleModalOpen}
        />
        {/* <SignUpModal
           modalOpen={this.state.modalOpen}
           handleModalOpen={this.handleModalOpen}
        /> */}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Login.js`, it's written using class-based syntax, hence it has to be `this.props` instead of `props`

```js
<Modal show={this.props.modalOpen} onHide={this.props.handleModalOpen}>
```

Alternatively, `Login.js` can be rewrite into `functional-based component`, you can then use `props` like below

```js
const Login = props => {
  return (
    <Modal show={props.modalOpen} onHide={props.handleModalOpen} />
  )
}
```

Comment: Just so it's clear, in the constructor, it's the `props` parameter, so it's ok as-is. Anywhere else in the class, this answer is right!

Comment: @Isaac Wow, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks so much!

Comment: @EmileBergeron: Hence I've provided the exact line with `Modal` that's throwing the error, together with another example for functional-based component

Comment: @GalaXee95: Glad to help, do mark it as answer if it correctly answer your question  :)

Comment: Yes, like I said you're right (upvoted as well) ;) There's also hooks now if you want a function component that has a state.

Comment: @EmileBergeron: Oh yes Hooks of course! I'm so 2018 haha, let me update my answer